# Create relationship based on other relationship

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and Graph database. I have created sample db and try to learn thing. I have create normal relationship under that and connected node. I have question that is that possible to create relationship based on other relationship.

For Example: IF I take company organization example then there is only one CEO of company. There are many employees of that company. Like Software Engineer LEADESBY Team Leader and Team Leader MANAGEDBY is Project Manager. Now support I want to identify who is Project Manager then I create relationship from Software Engineer to Project Manager but I don't want to do this. Instead of this I will think about new relationship called LEADES->MANAGEDBY is ProjectManager. Is that Possible ?

Comment: What are the nodes that you'd want to connect?

Comment: I don't want relationship between node. I want to virtual relation like who is my Project Manager if I am software Engineer. For this I want to travel to LEADESBY to ManagedBY then I get PM of software engineer without creating relation between Software Engineer and PM directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here's the situation you describe in cypher:

```
CREATE (se:SoftwareEngineer {name: "Bob"})-[:LEAD_BY]->(tl:TeamLeader {name: "Mark"});

MATCH (tl:TeamLeader {name: "Mark"})
CREATE (tl)-[:MANAGED_BY]->(pm:ProjectManager {name: "Gil"})
```

Bob the software engineer is lead by team leader Mark.   Mark is managed by Project Manager "Gil".

Now from here, there are several ways of interpreting your question:

**How do we figure out who the Project Managers Are?**

You specify that if there's a `LEAD_BY` relationship followed by a `MANAGED_BY` relationship, that person is a PM.  So no, you don't need to create a new relationship from `SoftwareEngineer` to `ProjectManager` directly, instead you just need to traverse two relationships, like this:

```
MATCH (p)-[:LEAD_BY]->(q)-[:MANAGED_BY]->(pm)
RETURN pm;
```

If you can be more specific (like using the labels I did above), then you could also do it this way:

```
MATCH (se:SoftwareEngineer)-[:LEAD_BY]->(tl:TeamLead)-[:MANAGED_BY]->(pm:ProjectManager)
RETURN se, tl, pm;
```

This would give you a complete list of all 3-level management relationships.

In general, you can use these cypher queries to navigate as many levels deep in the pattern, as long as you can specify it.